# How to set the default mode of file in Spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs

Every time I open a .js file with Spacemacs, the default mode is `web-mode`. But what I want is `react-mode`.

Is there any way to achieve this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I found some information from [#4751](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/4751).

We can simply add `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.js\\'" . react-mode))` to `docspacemacs/user-config` in `.spacemacs`.